# Rails rolling up values in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I'm quite new to Rails, so forgive me if I'm going about this in the wrong way.

I have a model, transaction, which has an amount associated with it. However, since the amount is calculated as the sum of the amounts on a child model (transactor), I didn't want to create redundancy by actually having an amount field on my transaction table. I'd like to be able to get and set the amount at the transaction level (a value set at the transaction would be divided evenly among the transactors).

My question is this: Is composed_of the appropriate implementation for this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think `composed_of` is what you want. The read part is actually pretty easy:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transactors
  ...
  def amount
    self.transactors.sum(:amount)
  end
  ...
end
```

The write part (evenly dividing up among child models) is pretty unusual though and a bit more complicated, I suppose you'd do something like this:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transactors
  ...
  def amount=(value)
    self.transactors.each do |transactor|
      transactor.update_attributes(:amount => value.to_f / self.transactors.count)
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: This is what I would do for vanilla Ruby, I just wasn't certain this was the appropriate way in Rails. I thought perhaps composed_of might have add addition Rails-specific functionality that I might want. So, am I right in thinking that composed_of is used mainly to abstract fields in the database up to the next example (like the Money or address examples in the docs). Is there another use for it?